# How to convert body frame-relative aerodynamic coefficients to wind frame-relative aerodynamic coefficients

Tags: aerodynamics, flight-controls, flight-dynamics, flight-simulator, rocket

I have a rocket flight simulator that takes in aerodynamic coefficients defined relative to the vehicle body frame axes (Cx, Cy, Cz). These are in a lookup table based on mach.

I have some aerodynamic coefficients that are given relative to the wind frame (Cd, Cl), also with a lookup based on mach, and I would like to input these into the simulator.

Is there a good way to convert the coefficients to the body frame so that they can be compatible with my simulator?

I know that I could modify the simulator code to make the transformation at runtime, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it where I could convert the coefficient lookup table itself.

Comment: Does [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/84008/64684) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All it takes is a 'little' trig.  If you want more information than you need, check out [AEDC-TR-63-224](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/AD0422287.pdf).  To skip to the answer, look at eq 42:

[image: screenshot of equation 42]

Comment: I considered this a case of LMGTFY and only pasted in the link to the technical paper that derives the equations, lays out the nomenclature, and explains everything.  Ralph copy/pasted the final answer (the image with some letters) feeling that made the answer more complete.